# Cassandra cluster returns incorrect error "Keyspace does not exist" when connecting from one specific pc

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cassandra

I have a small Cassandra cluster hosted on AWS that I want to connect to using the python drivers. Unfortunately I get "Keyspace does not exist" when trying to connect to it from one specific pc. The strange thing is that keyspace exists and I can connect to itfrom other pcs. And I can find that keyspace on that server in cqlsh. How do I fix this error? I've looked into the cassandra version, 3.7.1 which should work fine with my updated python driver. The error is reliably repeatable on that pc. And I can reliably connect to that keyspace on other pcs.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the query from your python driver is using upper case letters for the keyspace name - change it to lower case

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this keyspace is visible in a list that driver on problematic pc gets when connecting to the cluster i.e. :

```
>>> from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
>>> cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.2'])
>>> session = cluster.connect()
>>> for key in cluster.metadata.keyspaces:
...   print key
...
system_schema
system_auth
system
system_distributed
system_traces
hello2
hello3
hello_stack
```

Comment: I just did that. Strangely enough there is no difference. The problematic keyspace is visible in that list.